# How I can use coulours in Markdown Syntax?

Tags: discussion, design

Hello How I can use colours/background colours in texts.

I tried`<div bgcolor="#F5E9E9" colour="#B5000">coloured text</div>`

But it does nothing.

Comment: You can't. At least I *hope* you can't...

Comment: @JonK Too bad for some ARTS sites.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. They're annoying. There's no reason you'd ever need to do that.

The only text coloring that Stack Exchange supports is through the [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) features for code blocks.

Comment: That's too bad for some ARTS sites.